# Challenging: Ignore special characters in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a very simple script that prints on screen what ever passed to it on the first argument, the string always come out wrong, and the problem is that this script is being called from another program and passes a variable to that script as the first argument, so there is no way for me to alter the string itself, but only how it is being called or passed.

e.g.

```
var string=test@$134!'
ssh user@server ./echo_string.sh #string#
```

#string# is how I'm passing the variable to shell script, this get replaced with `test@$134!'`, but it doesn't show on the logs and never gets printed.

When I call the script with `./echo_string.sh #string#` the output the I'm looking for is this
`test@$134!'`

Kindly note that the previous is just an example and the string can have any special characters at any position

Comment: What exactly do you expect `#string#` to do? It is a comment, start to finish; nothing is passed to the program. Also, what is `var` and what should it do?

Comment: #string# is a datastage parameter that is being set by other party, so you can think of it as a variable that is being replace with `test@$134!'`

Comment: `string='test@$134!'"'"; printf '#%s#\n' "$string";` ← This expands just fine. Even `echo "#${string}#";` would work (given that it doesn’t start with `-` or other somewhat special characters). Now it’s just a matter of replacing `echo` with the real thing.

Comment: There also no guarantee that it doesn't start with -, the string can have any special characters at any position

Comment: For something like this, it's vital to understand the entire sequence of processing/parsing steps the string (password) is going to go through on its way to its ultimate destination. How exactly is the string provided to the script? You said it's a "datastage parameter", but I don't know what that means. Is there some preprocessing stage that substitutes it into the script before the script is executed, or is it just passed as an argument to something like `execve()`, or as part of a shell command (e.g. `/path/to/shell "test@\$134!'"`), or what?

Comment: Also, it looks like you're passing it over `ssh`, so it's also important to understand what's going to happen on the other side of the `ssh` connection: what shell will it be parsed by, and how's it used as part of the remote command. Finally, exactly what control do you have over each of these steps? Can you change how it's passed to the script, what's on the remote side of the `ssh` connection, etc?

Comment: Ignoring special characters _after the script is started_ is easy. Ignoring special characters _in a command line being passed to ssh_ is a separate matter (and we already have answered Q&A entries describing how to do it). Please narrow this to _one_ specific, clear question -- we shouldn't need to guess which aspect of the general problem you're stuck on.

Comment: In general: `${var@Q}` expands to shell syntax that, when parsed by the same shell, will expand to the same value as `"$var"`. `${array[*]@Q}` does the same for an array. So if you have `cmd=( ./echo_string.sh '#string# )`, f/e, then you can get `cmd_q=${cmd[*]@Q}` to get something where you can `ssh hostname "$cmd_q"` _if the remote shell is guaranteed to be bash_ (and not `sh` or something else). And again, the details on how to adopt this to handle cases where the remote shell _isn't_ bash are already elsewhere in our knowledge base.

Comment: (There's also the question of whether you're correctly escaping your contents so they parse to the intended literals in the first place, but if you don't show us _exactly_ what you're doing we aren't in a place to speculate).

Comment: What shell is `var string=xyz`? I've never seen the `var` keyword and it does not work in bash. `#` starts a comment and everything after is ignored. `set -x` might help you in debugging the script, it will print each command and its arguments as it is being executed

Answer (score 1):

So is the other program simply calling `popen("yourscript.sh test@$134!'")` or a similar API call that uses a single string?

If this is the case then that application must work harder to escape `test@$134!'` - it needs to escape the `$` the `'` and the `!` perhaps also the `@` and certain other characters if they are present against the popen shell performing interpretation. I.e. call `popen("yourscript.sh test\@\$134\!\'")` . Depending on the language you may have to double-escape these characters to ensure the language string processor does not consume the backslash: `popen("yourscript.sh test\\@\\$134\\!\\'")` - you would need this if the caller was C or C++.

In many cases, simply using explicit double-quotes around the argument would be enough, as that causes many shell escapes to not be attempted - but because your string contains a dollar sign ($) some, or all of the phrase might be interpreted as a shell variable. Using single quotes round the phrase is an even more powerful anti-processor, but then the single quote you have in the string is an issue. Perhaps using a quotes wrapper reduces the number of symbols that you then need to escape (singlequote for singlequote vs $ and doublequote for doublequote)

If that caller program is using an array of arguments API like `exec({"yourscript.sh", "test@$134!'"})` and the documentation says the call is direct with no shell, then there is no risk of the argument being interpreted before it gets to your script,  but you may want to directly call the script interpreter from the caller program: `exec({"/bin/bash", "yourscript.sh", "test@$134!'"})`.

Then the problem probably is in your script. You need to ensure that whenever you use $1 you quote it as "$1" to ensure that it is not expanded. If you copy the $1 to a named variable then remember to quote that always.

You may need to do both these fixes.

If you are concerned that the argument might be interpreted as a command option, then you need to check the syntax of the commands you are using. Many commands support a special `--` option which suppresses the option processor. But some do not. I'm not sure if there is a legal way to `echo` the string "-E" as a single command. Though `echo` does try to be generous and prints the whole word if it sees any characters that are not options, so `echo -End` works fine (in bash). Bash also supports a printf command, so you could use that: `printf "%s\n" "-e"` - any options have to be before the format string, so the injections cannot be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0):

try this pls:

```
var string='test@$134!'"'"
```

1. Im escaping "!" with single quote
2. Im adding a single quote at the end with "'"

In my shell, the variable print exactly as you want.